# Python 2.7.6 'no module named dummy'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module

I am trying to practice the multi-thread. And I find a tutorial from web.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
def calcPi_thread(nuFutures,tries,n):
    ts = time.time()

    #define the Pool
    p = Pool(n)
    #use multi-thread to run function 'test'
    result = p.map(test,[tries]*nbFutures)

    ret = 4.*sum(result)/float(nbFutures*tries)
    span = time.time()-ts
    print "Time Spend for Mutli-Thread(Thread=" + str(n) + ") is " + str(span)
    return ret
```

When I run the code above, it said 'No module named dummy'. multiprocessing.dummy is default module in Python 2.7.6? Do I need to install this module manually?

Comment: I assume the error is on the first line and that the rest of the code is irrelevant. The import worked for me on Ubuntu python 2.7.6.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?  Also, your script isn't named `multiprocessing.py` is it?

Comment: @jedwards OP has yet to return, I'll go ahead and say you are a wizard.

Comment: @jedwards yes...That is the issue..How stupid I am..lol